# How to install Perl modules with dependencies offline on Windows and Strawbery Perl?

Tags: perl, installation, offline, strawberry-perl, cpanm

I need to install Strawberry Perl and many Perl modules (with dependencies) on a Windows machine without the access to the internet (for security reasons).

Offline installation of Strawberry Perl works perfectly, but I did not manage to install additional modules I need.

I prepared a CPAN like repository on a Ubuntu machine using [Pinto](http://search.cpan.org/~thaljef/Pinto-0.09995/lib/Pinto/Manual/QuickStart.pod):

```bash
pinto --root my_repo init
pinto --root my_repo pull -M Some::Mudule1 Some::Mudule2
```

Then I transferred `my_repo` directory to the target machine as `C:\some\path\my_repo` and tried:

```bash
cpanm --mirror "file://C:/some/path/my_repo" --mirror-only Some::Mudule1 Some::Mudule2
```

But it ended up with error message:

```
! cannot open file 'C:\Users\dedek/.cpanm/sources/file%C%some%path%my_repo/02packages.details.txt.gz': No such file or directory opening compressed index
! Couldn't find module or a distribution Some::Mudule1
! cannot open file 'C:\Users\dedek/.cpanm/sources/file%C%some%path%my_repo/02packages.details.txt.gz': No such file or directory opening compressed index
! Couldn't find module or a distribution Some::Mudule2
```

Why is `cpanm` looking for such strange location? How can I fix it? Is there a simpler way how to install Perl modules offline? It would be also nice if I could prepare the CPAN like repository on a Windows machine. But I did not succeed to install Pinto on Windows, is it possible?

Comment: From a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825188 I noticed that Strawberry Perl PortableZIP edition may solve the problem. But I'm still curious what is wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found my mistake. There is a symbolic link `modules -> stacks/master/modules` in the original 
CPAN like repository made by Pinto. And this link was discarded during the transfer (using WinSP). When I copied `my_repo/stacks/master/modules` to `my_repo/modules` everything worked correctly.

I would really appreciate a more relevant error message from `cpanm`!